# ImportError: No module named 'forget_mult_cuda' error while using QRNN based pretrained Language model

Tags: python-3.x, text, fast-ai

I am trying to use a QRNN based encoder for text classification by tuning a QRNN pretrained LM.

Here is the configuration of qrnn

```
emb_sz:int = 400
nh: int = 1550
nl: int = 3

qrnn_config = copy.deepcopy(awd_lstm_lm_config)
dps = dict(output_p=0.25, hidden_p=0.1, input_p=0.2, embed_p=0.02, weight_p=0.15)
qrnn_config.update({'emb_sz':emb_sz, 'n_hid':nh, 'n_layers':nl, 'pad_token':1, 'qrnn':True})
qrnn_config
```

I am passing configuration to lm_learner

```
lm_learner = language_model_learner(data_lm, AWD_LSTM, config=qrnn_config, pretrained=False,drop_mult=.1,pretrained_fnames=(pretrained_lm_fname,pretrained_itos_fname))
```

What I am getting is:

```
ImportError: No module named 'forget_mult_cuda'
```

Fast-ai version is: '1.0.51.dev0'

Answer (score 0):

Try cleaning cuda cash using

```
gc.collect()
torch.cuda.empty_cache()
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this for updating QRnn to `true`

language model

```
config = awd_lstm_lm_config.copy()
config['qrrn']=True
```

Classification model

```
config = awd_lstm_clas_config.copy()
config['qrrn']=True
```

config
You need not copy anything from source code.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you're missing ninja package.

Use:

```
pip install ninja
```

And restart your notebook, if you're using it.